# Alternative in laravel for code-block

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am learning laravel5.3 and `{!!  !!}` this is a lot been used in tutorials. Is there any alternatives for it? I searched on google I didn't get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `{{ }}`. Take a look at this tutorial `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hdD7np4VrQ#t=326.206833`